# Inflate MapFragment in service

Tags: android, service, maps, fragment

I'm trying to create an app that is an overlay over other apps. As such I'm using a service with WindowManager and addView. I have successfully been able to show a simple ImageView window over other apps, but what about showing a fragment in this overlay window? Is it possible? Can I just inflate a layout and add that with windowManger.addView ? I tried inflating a layout that contains a SupportMapFragment and I'm getting this error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.teqtic.minimap-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can't programmatically inflate an XML layout that contains a fragment.